# How to forbid an (emoji) font only for one software?

Tags: fonts, fontconfig, suckless-terminal, emoji, xft

### Context :

I'm using Luke Smith's version of `st` (suckless-terminal) with [Monoid](https://larsenwork.com/monoid/) font for most Unicode symbols,
and I noticed it usually crash when it sees some emojis, like `U1F970`, `st` tries to load a color emoji font (currently, it's `Apple Color Emoji`, but for other users the default is with `Noto Color Emoji`, I tried both and it had the same issue) and crashes :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RENDER)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  20 (RenderAddGlyphs)
  Serial number of failed request:  850
  Current serial number in output stream:  883
```

If I want to avoid this crashes, I have several "unsatisfying" solutions :

- Don't use `st` at all. And don't use any other softwares that has the same issue.
- I installed `ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola`. I can use it and have colorless emojis everywhere.
  With this solution, I need to remove colored emojis, because every time I have `Noto` or `Apple` with colored emojis, it's taken by default instead of `Symbola`.
- Disable the font when I launch `st` (a `.` before the file name is enough to hide it), and enable it again after that. Looks like cheat and may cause problems when another software is launched.
- Store emojis on personal `user` folder, create another user `user_2`, launch `st` with `user_2` and become `user` again.
  Is there a way to do this ? If so, is it the simplest way to avoid crashes ?
- Use the solution from [Luke Smith's St on Github](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st/blob/master/README.md) :
  `If st crashes when viewing emojis, install libxft-bgra from the AUR.`
   will probably not work for me because I'm not using an Arch-based distro
  (I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04LTS. If someone knows a way to safely use AUR on it, why not, but it seems very unlikely).

### What I want to do :

Tell to my computer to allow `Apple Color Emoji` to every software except those I chose 
(currently, it's only `st` and `pango-view` (I use the second one only for a few tests), or other softwares using `xft`),
and tell `st` to use any "allowed for `st`" thing it wants for emojis, preferably `Symbola`.

Or tell to my computer at least to take `Symbola` by default for the `emoji` family.
If possible, "by default only for `st`".

I think there could be a solution with `font-config`.

### Things I tried (non exhaustive) :

With `font-config`, there are tags like `<match><test><string>st</string></test>…</match>` to target `st` only
(I was able to tell it to "Make a font bold, only for st, only for some sizes". It worked on my computer).
And there are other tags like `<selectfont><rejectfont><glob>/path/to/emoji/font</glob></rejectfont></selectfont>` to disallow globally exactly one (or several, with a glob pattern) font.

I tried to combine them but it looks impossible. Here is a code that does not work :

(the font is removed everywhere, not "only for `st`").

```
<match>
    <test qual="all" name="prgname" target="pattern" compare="eq"><string>St</string></test>
    <selectfont>
        <rejectfont>
            <glob>/home/user/.local/share/fonts/Apple*</glob>
        </rejectfont>
    </selectfont>
</match>
```

I think a `<selectfont>` tag isn't supposed to be inside a `<match>` tag.

---

This [issue](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/voidrice/issues/284) is actually known, and not only related to `st`. I tried almost every solution here but still have crashes.
Example of what I tried, similar to a suggestion someone made about this issue :

```
<match target="pattern">
  <test name="family"><string>emoji</string></test>
  <edit name="family" mode="append"><string>Symbola</string></edit>
</match>
<match target="pattern">
  <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Apple Color Emoji</string></test>
   <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Symbola</string></edit>
</match>
```

but with or without it, the output of `fc-match --verbose :family=emoji | grep '^.family:` 
remains `family: "Apple Color Emoji"(s)`.

It still does not works for me when I write `monospace` instead of `emoji` and the default monospace font instead of `Apple Color Emoji`. Am I doing something wrong here ?

---

I found a solution to set a default font (in the following [example](https://jichu4n.com/posts/how-to-set-default-fonts-and-font-aliases-on-linux/) ),

```
<alias>
  <family>monospace</family>
  <prefer><family>Cantarell</family></prefer>
</alias>
```

I set `monospace` to a random font called `Cantarell` and it worked.
It also worked for other fonts, including
But if I write `emoji` instead of `monospace`, here, it works !
So, there is a way to change default font. That's a good start, but it does not target a software, and `emoji` doesn't seems to be treated the same way `sans-serif` or `serif` or `monospace` are.
If I enable both `Noto Color Emoji` and `Apple Color Emoji`, the default for emojis is `Noto Color Emoji` and this solution didn't let me set `Apple Color Emoji` to default again.

I also noticed this config works with `sans-serif` (instead of `monospace`), but not with `sans`, even if `:family=sans` and `:family=sans-serif` has similar results every time I tried it on `fc-match`. Same remark for `mono` instead of `monospace`. Maybe, it means the words`sans`, `mono`, and `emoji` have something in common.

But what is this "something in common" ?
Is there a way to make `emoji` works like `monospace` does?

Comment: I have the same problem, and I have no solution, just a workaround: I uninstalled `fonts-noto-color-emoji`. Now I have no coloured emojis but st works. This is fine be me, because I don't care for them.

Comment: I have posted this question 1 year ago. I still don't have a solution. I'm currently doing like you : I don't use colored emojis.